# Name of a common pattern-matching functional operator

Tags: functional-programming

In functional programming, what is the *name* (or name of the concept) of the following functional operator `P`?:

> Given two functions `f` and `g`, and predicate function `p`, `P(p, f, g)` is the function
>
> ```
> x → if (p(x)) f(x) else g(x)
> ```

I am wondering whether this operator has an established name, so that I can use that name in my code. (That is, I want to give `P` a conventional name.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's the `if` operator lifted into the function monad.

For example in Haskell, you can literally do

```hs
import Control.Monad
let if' c t f = if c then t else f  -- another common name is `ite`
let ifM = liftM3 if'                -- admittedly the type of this is too generic
--        ^^^^^^^^^^
let example = ifM even (\x -> "t "++show x) (\x -> "f "++show x)
example 1 -- "f 1"
example 2 -- "t 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another haskell example [Point-wise conditional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Boolean-0.2.4/docs/Data-Boolean.html#v:cond) in Boolean library

```hs
cond :: (Applicative f, IfB a, bool ~ BooleanOf a) => f bool -> f a -> f a -> f a
```

it takes [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) that holds bool, two another `Applicatives` with values for `True` and `False` cases and produces `Applicative` result.

There are different types that are `Applicative` and function is just one of them.

```hs
> f = cond (\x -> x > 1) (\x -> x / 10) (\x -> x * 10)
> f 2.0  
# 0.2
> f 0.13 
#1.3
```

Optional value `Maybe` is another useful example

```hs
> cond (Just True) (Just 10) (Just 20)
# Just 10
> cond (Just True) (Just 10) Nothing
# Nothing
```

`List` is also `Applicative`

```hs
> cond [True, False, True] [10] [1, 2]
# [10,10,1,2,10,10]
> cond [True, False, True] [10] [1]
# [10, 1, 10]
> cond [True, False, True] [10] []
# []
```